# Show trailing zeros in C++

Tags: c++, precision

I am trying to print a decimal number however when printing the trailing zeros are always removed.

e.g.
If I input the number 100 I would like it to print 100.00
If I input the number 12.506 I would like it to print 12.50

For this program I was limited to the iostream and fstream libraries. I tried using precision but it removes the trailing zeros.

Comment: Use `fixed` as well as `setprecision`, `cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 100.0;`

Comment: I cannot use setprecision since that requires iomanip library and I could only use iostream and fstream.  However I was able to figure out my problem by adding "fixed"

Comment: Very strange but `cout.precision(2)` works just as well.

Comment: Surely you would prefer 12.506 to print 12.51? That is what you will get, anyway.